# Python Finding local maxima and minima on discrete data

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, finance, algorithmic-trading

[image]

Assuming this line is made up of discrete random numbers in pandas. How can I find point A,B,C,D?

A is the highest point between the first point and C

C is the lowest point between A and B

B is the highest point between C and D

Another example could be like this
[image]

You can use this data to test:
[1, 2, 3, 10, 13, 15, 20, 50, 49, 49, 32, 33, 35, 36, 35, 34, 33, 34, 35, 36, 30, 27, 22, 15, 15, 17, 20, 27, 30, 32, 50, 56, 67, 85, 100, 99, 94, 83, 72, 59, 66, 67, 89, 90, 92, 127, 130, 189]

For the data above:

A = 50

B = 100

C = 15

D = 59

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain that the line is continuous (it doesn't have to be smooth), you could use a discrete gradient search by using a finite difference.

If you start to the left of A, you could calculate (y[i+1]-y[i]) (I'm omitting division by h because it's irrelevant for this purpose.) Just check if that's positive. And if it is, move forward and calculate it again. Actually, it would be easier to just write it.

```
def find_a():
    i=toTheLeftOfA
    done=false
    while not done:
        if y[i-1]-y[i]>0:
            i=i+1
        else:
            done=true
    return([i,y[i]])
## retrieve [X,Y(X)=A] as find_a()
```

I'm sure there are more clever things, like a binary search. But as long as you only have to do it once and not a million times every hour, this should work.

Comment: It's not continuous, thank you though

Comment: Right of course. I mean no curve stored as vectors is "continuous". But if it's monotonic for long stretches, and those stretches are divided by your points of interest, then this is essentially what a library would call logically. And if the curve isn't monotonic for long stretches, then the points you've described are likely abundant and not very interesting.